# Nested Lists and Automapper.Map

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper, dto

So I have 2 objects,AlbumDto and AlbumMediaDto.

```
public class AlbumDto
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? AlbumDate { get; set; }

    public AlbumMediasDto Media { get; set; }// list of media
}
```

And I have a method from the repo that would return a list of albums (where each has the properties mentioned above which includes a list of media)

```
var albumsForChild = await GetTenantRepository<IAlbumRepository>().GetAlbumsForChild(childId);
```

So I'm not sure how to map them to these Dtos using the AutoMapper ( I know that I can always use a nested foreach and fill everything accordingly but thought of learning how to do this the right way).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Was the documentation not sufficient? ([Lists](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html), [nested mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html)).

Comment: @KennethK. I have the config in a different file, are you implying that adding this to my config file (    cfg.CreateMap<Album, AlbumDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<AlbumMedia, AlbumMediaDto >();) and  using albumsDto = Mapper.Map<List<AlbumDto>>(albums);
should be enough? It will automatically link the inner lists?

Comment: as long as albumsDto is of type IEnumerable, above config should work

Answer (score 1):

Can you work with JSon deserialization?  If yes, below can be your solution.

Business logic:

```
public IEnumerable<AlbumDto> GetAllAlbums()
{
    var allAlbums = _theApiWrapper.ExecuteGet<IEnumerable<AlbumDto>>("theApiRoute");
    return allAlbums;
}
```

Repository:

```
public T ExecuteGet<T>(string endpoint)
{
    var uri = $"https://apiurl.company.com/api/v1/{endpoint}";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var x = client.GetAsync(uri);
        var result = x.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
            result, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on my infrastructure but otherwise sounds like a solution.