# Automatically serialize a JSON server response with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Learning C#. I'm using JSON.net to serialize and deserialize a server's response.

I do have a very small part working. For example, for OAuth2, I needed to send credentials to get an `access_token`. I had to do it via the following:

```
// Serialize the JSON response for the access_token
public class AccessToken
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
}

static async void GetCrmAccessToken(FormUrlEncodedContent content)
{
    try
    {
        // Send the x-www-form-urlencoded info to the OAuth2 end point
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync("https://login.windows.net/42daf6bc-f7add741ac61/oauth2/token", content);
        // Get the body from the response
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Extract out the access token from the repsonse
        AccessToken responseBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(responseContent);

        if (responseBody.access_token != "")
        {
            // If there is an access token, take it and use it in
            // generating the query
            RequestCrmQuery(responseBody.access_token);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not get the access token.");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Basically had to create a class with a public variable for the key that I wanted out of the JSON.

Now that I have the access token, the response from the query is significantly larger.

1. Do I have to create a public variable for each key I want to work with JSON response? (There are dozens).
2. Can this be serialized automatically? If so, how?
3. Some of the keys in the server response have crazy names like `biz_status@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue`. Can't create a variable with that name in C#. How would that work give that is one of the important keys I need to work with?
4. Can I call the variable something else, but explicitly state the key in the JSON that it corresponds to?

Comment: "create a method for each key"??? Check if you main account searched about automatically creating classes from JSON.

Comment: Yeah, not following what you are saying.

Comment: Please keep each question 1 and only 1 question. Otherwise the answer will be like: yes, yes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398171/map-entity-to-json-using-javascriptserializer) and yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I have to create a public variable for each key I want to work with JSON response? (There are dozens).
**Define only you need.**

Can this me serialized automatically? If so, how?
**YES.  See implementation in this answer:**
[Nested Lists and Automapper.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104181/nested-lists-and-automapper-map/53104760#53104760)

Some of the keys in the server response have crazy names like: biz_status@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue. Can't create a variable with that name in C#. How would that work given that is one of the important keys I need to work with?

**Create properties like this:**

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "InconsistentNaming")]
[SerializePropertyNamesAsCamelCase]
public class SearchResult
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("abstract")]
    public string[] Abstract { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dateIssued")]
    public DateTime? DateIssued { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@search.score")]
    public decimal Score { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@search.highlights")]
    public Highlights Highlights { get; set; }
}
```

Can I call the variable something else, but explicitly state the key in the JSON that it corresponds to?
**YES.  See above implementation**

Answer (score 2):

The are three main ways to work with a json:

1. Using json.net's JObject, where you can fetch properties, use JPath to access specific nodes (similar to XPath). The good news are that you don't need to create classes, but it performs a bit slower that serializing to an object.
2. De-serializing to a .net object. You will need to create the structure for every needed property.
3. De-serializing to a dynamic\expando object - This gives you the ability to work with a dynamic type. No need to create classes as well.

As for your questions:

1. Answered above. If you use the De-serialization to object, you will need to create all the properties you want to access.
2. There are some clients that perform serialization behind the scenes. I prefer using a native client and do the De-serialization myself. You can always create something custom pretty fast.
3. You can use the `[JsonProperty("<name of json property")]` attribute above any property.

   `[JsonProperty("realNodeName")]
    public string MyCoolProperty {get;set;}`
4. Same as (3).